# How to check through which selector jQuery has selected the element

Tags: jquery, selector

I'm using multiple classes as a selector like this:

```
jQuery(".class1 , class2 , .class3").function(){}
```

Now I want to check through which class the element has been selected.

Like and element which has the class "class1", will be selected the in this case the required result would be "class1". I can do that by using `.hasClass()` function but I don't want to use that. Is there any other way to do that?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: can you post a snippet or the full code of what exactly you've done or you're trying to do?

Comment: `e.target` ? did you try

Comment: Since under the hood it's probably using the vanilla [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), it's probably not possible without querying for a specific class, nor does it make sense to me that it would be needed.

Comment: @Shinratensei Here it is

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/6qnkykht/)

Comment: @guradio, Yes I tried, It didn't worked as I want

Comment: hmmmm I'm sorry but I still don't understand your objective. With selector you mean radio buttons, selects, check boxes...?

Comment: @Shinratensei Did you checked this https://jsfiddle.net/6qnkykht/ ?

Comment: @hussainnayani you can't have a number as a class.. A valid class name must start with a letter or underscore..

Comment: @ShadowFiend , thanks for you correction but that was just an example.

Comment: @hussainnayani yes I did, but all I see are 5 divs, how can I know what you want to make with only that?

Comment: @Shinratensei I've added javascript code too.

Comment: @hussainnayani I saw that too. Still, I'm not being able to understand your objective. I hope the answers that people already made help you, because I feel unable to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what class triggered the function, try the following:

The reason i added the code below, is that if the element has multiple classes then we only get the one that contains class. so we know what class triggered this.

```
.split(/\s/).filter(function(cn) {
  return cn.indexOf('class') === 0;
}).join()
```

```js
jQuery(".class1 , .class2 , .class3").click(function(e) {
  var c = $(e.target).attr("class").split(/\s/).filter(function(cn) {
    return cn.indexOf('class') === 0;
  }).join()

  console.log(c)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class1 t">class1</div><br>
<div class="class2 e">class2</div><br>
<div class="class3 l">class3</div><br>
```

Comment: This is just an attempt to mimic jQuery `hasClass()` method.

Comment: He's asking if there was another way, but I respect your opinion

Comment: What if an element had 2 of the classes?

Comment: As I answered, there is no other way and one way or another at the end he has to check if element has the class - best to use existing jQuery's method.

Comment: @skobaljic any point of why you're getting all mad at me? The OP asking for another way, I provided that.

Comment: Not at all, he just said he did not want to check the class, but your answer is about checking the class. Think you agree jQuery guys already did it best way. Cheers

Answer (score -2):

There is **no other way**, simply check if element has the class:

```
if( $(this).hasClass('class1') ) { ... };
```